# While coding a GPT clone, Why my GPT-3.5 API, text_davinci_003 is printing an unusual, irrelevant and unwanted code in between

Tags: javascript

I am making a JavaScript application which uses GPT-3.5 and renders responses on my website. It is basically a clone of ChatGPT you can say...

But the issue is that, after rendering some responses it generates some irrelevant text in between the conversation.

To find the solution, I tried to generate another API key and use it, but it didn't work. I tried to use the text_davinci_002 but still, It didn't work at all... I tried to change my code in several ways but it's the same problem persisting...

Have a look at Server.js:-

```
import express from "express";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from 'cors';
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

dotenv.config();

const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({
        message: "Welcome to OpenAI API",
    });
});

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const prompt = req.body.prompt;

        const response = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: `${prompt}`,
            temperature: 0,
            max_tokens: 4000,
            top_p: 1,
            frequency_penalty: 0.5,
            presence_penalty: 0,
        });
        res.status(200).send({
            bot: response.data.choices[0].text
        })
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send({ error })
    }
})

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Sever is running on port :- http://localhost:5000"))
```

And the irrelevant text or pretty much its a code that it generates is :-

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.example.demo.model.*;
import com.example.demo.*;

@RestController    // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") // This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)
public class MainController {
    @Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository
               // Which is auto-generated by Spring, we will use it to handle the data
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY GET Requests
    public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String email) {
        // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
        // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

        User n = new User();  // Create a new user object  and set its values  from the request parameters passed in  (name, email)  using setters   .save() will save it to db .   .findAll() will return list of all users in db as an iterable  .findById(id) will return user object with given id   .deleteById(id) will delete user with given id   .deleteAll() will delete all users in db   .existsById(id) will check if there is a user with given id in db and return true or false accordingly  .count() will return number of users in db    .getOne(id) returns proxy instead of data and only fetches data when some method like getName() is called on it    .saveAndFlush() saves data and refreshes session immediately     */ 

        n.setName(name);      // Set its name and email values using setters   (setName(), setEmail())    */ 
        n.setEmail(email);    // Set its name and email values using setters   (setName(), setEmail())    */ 

        userRepository.save(n);     // Save it to database using save() method of JpaRepository interface which UserRepository class implements     */ 

        return "Saved";            // Return string "Saved" as response      */ 
         }                          /*                                          */ 

         @GetMapping(path="/all")       /* Map ONLY GET Requests                  */  public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {       /* @ResponseBody means the returned Iterable<User> is the response, not a view name      */                                                              /* Return list of all users in database as an iterable using findAll() method of JpaRepository interface which UserRepository class implements     */                                                              /* findAll() returns all the entries of table as a list      */        return userRepository
```

Kindly, Help me with this issue...
Hoping for a quick response
Thank you!

Comment: ChatGPT is generating rubbish? It does that. A lot. Unless this question is somehow about the code you've written, it's off topic here. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/14853083

Comment: Yes, It is generating rubbish... Every time
But, I wanted to know if my code itself is somewhere wrong...
I Apologies that I asked about ChatGPT

Answer (score 0):

1- Use ChatGPT for generating code related problems,because is more capable model for this task.
2 -  read the basic of prompting, If someone wants to debug your code need the prompts as completions. https://help.openai.com/en/collections/3675942-prompt-engineering